# Android: GridView Item Click go to One Fragment to Another Fragment

Tags: android, gridview, fragment

I have a tab bar in the bottom. There are four tabs in it. This is the code of one the tabs. I want to go to another Fragment when I click on a gridview item but the tabs remain the same only the fragment changes.The code has no errors but when I click on the gridview items it doesn't work.
This is my FeedFragment.java

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.GridView;

public class FeedFragment extends Fragment {
    GridView grid;
String[] web= new String[]{"Free drinks for ladies in the bar",
        "Saturday Night live at fork you",
        "Free drinks for ladies in the bar",
        "Free drinks for ladies in the bar",
        "Free drinks for ladies in the bar",
        "Free drinks for ladies in the bar",
        "Free drinks for ladies in bar",
        "Free drinks for ladies",
        "Free drinks for ladies",
        "Free drinks for ladies",
        "Free drinks for ladies",
        "Free drinks for ladies",
        "Free drinks for ladies",

        "Blogger"};
        int[] imageid={R.drawable.newfeed,
                R.drawable.newfeed,
                R.drawable.newfeed,
                R.drawable.newfeed,
                R.drawable.newfeed,
                R.drawable.newfeed,
                R.drawable.newfeed,
                R.drawable.newfeed,
                R.drawable.newfeed,
                R.drawable.newfeed,
                R.drawable.newfeed};
String[] name={"Natasha Sethi" ,
        "Natasha Sethi" ,
        "Natasha Sethi" ,
        "Natasha Sethi" ,
        "Natasha Sethi" ,
        "Natasha Sethi" ,
        "Natasha Sethi" ,
        "Natasha Sethi" ,
        "Natasha Sethi" ,
        "Natasha Sethi" ,"Natasha Sethi" ,"Natasha Sethi" ,
        "Natasha Sethi" ,
        "Blogger" };
    String[] time={
             "5m ago" ,
            "5m ago" ,
            "5m ago" ,
            "5m ago" ,
            "5m ago" ,
            "5m ago" ,
            "5m ago" ,"5m ago" ,
            "5m ago" ,
            "5m ago" ,
            "5m ago" ,
            "5m ago" ,
            "5m ago" ,

            "Blogger"
    };
    int[] imagelike={
            R.drawable.like,
            R.drawable.like,
            R.drawable.like,
            R.drawable.like,
            R.drawable.like,
            R.drawable.like,
            R.drawable.like,
            R.drawable.like,
            R.drawable.like,
            R.drawable.like,
            R.drawable.like
    };
    int[] personimg={
            R.drawable.white,
            R.drawable.white, R.drawable.white, R.drawable.white, R.drawable.white, R.drawable.white, R.drawable.white, R.drawable.white, R.drawable.white, R.drawable.white, R.drawable.white, R.drawable.white, R.drawable.white, R.drawable.white, R.drawable.white, R.drawable.white, R.drawable.white, R.drawable.white
    };

Intent intent;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.feedmain, container, false);
        FeedCustomGrid adapter= new FeedCustomGrid(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),web,imageid,name,time,imagelike,personimg);


        grid=(GridView)view.findViewById(R.id.grid);

        grid.setAdapter(adapter);
        grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Fragment fragment = new Feed2();

                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.container_framelayout,fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();

        }});





    return view;}
            @Override
            public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);



}}
```

This is the FeedCustomGrid.Java

```
public class FeedCustomGrid extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private final String[] web;
    private final String[] name;
    private final String[] time;
    private final int[] Imageid;
    private final int[] imagelike;
    private final int[] personimg;

    public FeedCustomGrid(Context c, String[] web,int[] Imageid,String[] name,String[] time,int[] imagelike,int[] personimg) {

        mContext = c;
        this.Imageid = Imageid;
        this.web = web;
        this.name=name;
        this.time=time;
        this.imagelike=imagelike;
        this.personimg=personimg;
    }



    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return web.length;

    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View grid;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null) {

            grid = new View(mContext);
            grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feedmainitem, null);
            TextView textView = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            TextView textView26 = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.textView26);
            TextView textView29 = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.textView29);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView)grid.findViewById(R.id.imageView8);
            ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView)grid.findViewById(R.id.imageView17);
            ImageButton imageView2 = (ImageButton)grid.findViewById(R.id.imageButton12);
            textView.setText(web[position]);
            textView29.setText(time[position]);
            textView26.setText(name[position]);
            imageView.setImageResource(Imageid[position]);
            imageView2.setImageResource(imagelike[position]);
            imageView1.setImageResource(personimg[position]);
        } else {
            grid = (View) convertView;
        }

        return grid;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to add a new fragment inside the current or want to replace the current one ?

Comment: want to replace current with other

Comment: then use replace() instead of add().Try it

Comment: Not working after put replace() ...